# C++ Basic Constructor does not print out text

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I was just coding some basic C++, and I created a constructor inside a class. The constructor is meant to print out the name defined in the `main()` function, but for some reason when I run it, nothing happens. It's not really a huge problem, but I would like to find out why it doesn't work, so I know what to do later on!

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class ClassOne{
public:
    ClassOne(string z){
        setName(z);
    }
    void setName(string x){
        name = x;
    }
    string getName(){
        return name;
    }

private:
    string name;

};

int main()
{
ClassOne classOneObject("Hello World");
cout << classOneObject.getName();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maby you need to flush:cout << classOneObject.getName() << endl;

Comment: How is the call to the constructor supposed to print anything? It shouldn't, in the code you have shown.

Comment: Well I'm following a tutorial series and the code I have is pretty much exactly the same as on the tutorial.

Comment: Are you actually observing the output? Have you tried running the executable from a command prompt? Could be that the output is appearing very quickly and you're missing it, and looking at debugger output instead, which will be empty.

Comment: Then maybe your terminology is wrong. Your constructor should print nothing. You print the result of a call to `getName()`. BTW, see [this demo](http://ideone.com/0XupkF).

Comment: Ok now I understand, I did not write the question properly. What I ment to say is that the text itself is not printing out on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

What compiler/version do you use? Try changing your code to:

```
cout << classOneObject.getName() << endl;
```

What happens now? (If it works now, the reason is that you didn't flush cout.)

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks 12.11 and the compiler is called "GNU GCC Compiler"

Comment: OP claims the constructor is meant to print out something, which it really shouldn't according to the code sample posted.

Comment: I see... Could it be you didn't set your project type to console application? Do you see a console when you run your program?

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, that's true. I read it like he is expecting to see the output when running his program. Of course the output is really done in the main function.

Comment: Yeah it's set to a console application.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClassOne classOneObject fo("Hello World");
cout << fo.getName();
```